# Equivalent OpenVPN client (or similar) config for given Shrew Soft VPN Client

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn

I used Shrew Soft VPN Client for accessing the VPN at the office, but last release is from 2013 and Debian/Ubuntu dropped support for it. Now I am looking a compatible linux client to replace it. The config for Shrew Soft VPN Client is as follows:

```
n:version:4
n:network-ike-port:500
n:network-mtu-size:1380
n:client-addr-auto:1
n:network-natt-port:4500
n:network-natt-rate:15
n:network-frag-size:540
n:network-dpd-enable:1
n:client-banner-enable:1
n:network-notify-enable:1
n:client-dns-used:1
n:client-dns-auto:1
n:client-dns-suffix-auto:1
n:client-splitdns-used:1
n:client-splitdns-auto:1
n:client-wins-used:1
n:client-wins-auto:1
n:phase1-dhgroup:5
n:phase1-keylen:0
n:phase1-life-secs:86400
n:phase1-life-kbytes:0
n:vendor-chkpt-enable:0
n:phase2-life-secs:3600
n:phase2-life-kbytes:0
n:policy-nailed:0
n:policy-list-auto:1
s:network-host:IP-OF-MY-OFFICE
s:client-auto-mode:pull
s:client-iface:virtual
s:network-natt-mode:enable
s:network-frag-mode:enable
s:auth-method:mutual-psk
s:ident-client-type:fqdn
s:ident-server-type:any
s:ident-client-data:tunel3
b:auth-mutual-psk:THIS-IS-A-SECRET
s:phase1-exchange:aggressive
s:phase1-cipher:aes
s:phase1-hash:sha1
s:phase2-transform:auto
s:phase2-hmac:auto
s:ipcomp-transform:disabled
n:phase2-pfsgroup:5
s:policy-level:auto
```

Could OpenVPN connect to this VPN? Which config should I use? A bare minimum is ok, I suppose not all options are required. If OpenVPN is not capable another free/libre linux client is suitable too.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.shrew.net/software , we can see that Shrew Soft VPN Client
is a IpSec client .

So OpenVpn will not work  ( OpenVpn has his own protocol ) .

You can use charon-cmd as a ipsec client https://packages.debian.org/buster/charon-cmd

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I tried with charon-cmd but I don't know which option use for shared password.